# Adding a fancybox to this wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I am buiding a new portfolio, you can see here.
www.mikelucid.com

My issue comes because the  tags have other html in then including an overlay that wyou actually click. This has made adding the fancy box impossible.

Would any expert be willing to take  a quick peak?

I was trying to do soething like this but couldnt get it working :/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a.the_post").click(function(e) {
        var outerHTML = $("<div />").append($(this).find('.wp-post-image').clone()).html();
        console.log(outerHTML)
        $(this).fancybox({
            'content': outerHTML,
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your issue but this piece of code

```
$(this).fancybox({
    'content': outerHTML,
});
```

doesn't trigger fancybox, it only binds fancybox to the referred element every time you click on `a.the_post`

Try doing this instead

```
$.fancybox({
    'content': outerHTML,
});
```